# Why is this equivalent to an lbu?

Tags: assembly, mips

We have the following exercise:

> A program begins with:
>
> ```
> .data
> Input:
>     .word 0xAABBCCDD
> .text
>     addi $3, $0, Input
> ```
>
> Then the following four instructions follow:
>
> ```
>     addi $4, $0, 16
>     lw   $5, 0($3)
>     srav $5, $5, $4
>     andi $5, $5, 0xFF
> ```
>
> The CPU uses big endian encoding.
>
> Replace the four instructions by one single instruction that has the same effect.

The official answer is:

> ```
> lbu $5, 1($3)
> ```

I am not sure why the answer is why it is. Could someone explain please?

Comment: Bitwise `and` with `0xff` only leaves a single byte. Right shifting by 16 bits means it's going to be the second highest byte which due to big endian is at offset 1. Hence `1($3)`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure why the answer is why it is.

Actually, the answer is **wrong**:

The four instructions will load some data from RAM and modify the registers $4 and $5.

However, MIPS does not have any single instruction that is capable of reading data from RAM and modifying the values of **two** registers.

The "`lbu`" instruction will only replace the **last three of the four** instructions.

Here the explanation:

The following instruction:

> ```
> addi $4, $0, 16
> ```

... will load the value 16 into the register $4.

The word stored at address `Input` is `0xSTUVWXYZ` while each of the letters `R`...`Z` represent any hexadecimal digit. (In the example: `S`=`A`, `T`=`A`, `U`=`B` ...).

The following instruction:

> ```
> lw   $5, 0($3)
> ```

... will load the value `0xSTUVWXYZ` into the register $5.

The instruction:

> ```
> srav $5, $5, $4
> ```

... will shift the value in $5 (`0xSTUVWXYZ`) right by the number of bits given in register $4 (which contains the value 16).

The result will be `0x0000STUV` or `0xFFFFSTUV` depending on which hexadecimal digit is represented by the letter `S`. In the case of `0xAABBCCDD` the result will be `0xFFFFAABB`.

The result (`0xRRRRSTUV`) will be written to register $5.

The next instruction is:

> ```
> andi $5, $5, 0xFF
> ```

This instruction will perform a bit-wise `AND` operation with the value `0xFF`.

The value `0xFF` has the lower 8 bits set to 1 and all higher bits set to 0. This means that an `AND` operation of some value X (here: The value in register $5) and value `0xFF` would result in a number where the lower 8 bits are taken from X and the higher bits are set to 0:

`0xRRRRSTUV AND 0x000000FF = 0x000000UV`

The "replacement instruction" will work the following way:

> The CPU uses big endian encoding.

This means that `0xSTUVWXYZ` is stored as `0xST 0xUV 0xWX 0xYZ` and not as `0xYZ 0xWX 0xUV 0xST`.

> ```
> lbu $5, 1($3)
> ```

This instruction will load the second byte ($3 + 1) after the address specified by $3 and set the upper 24 bits of the destination register to 0.

This means that the byte `0xUV` will be loaded and the register $5 will contain the value `0x000000UV`.

---

By the way:

On a real system reading memory can have side-effects. One example is the RAM of an EGA or VGA graphics card.

On such graphics cards, the data actually written to the video RAM using a *write* operation (e.g. `sb`) depends on the previous *read* operation (e.g. `lb`).

When connecting a MIPS CPU to such a graphics card, the `sb` instructions in the following two pieces of code:

```
addi $4, $0, 16
lw   $5, 0($3)
srav $5, $5, $4
andi $5, $5, 0xFF
sb   $6, 12($3)
```

And:

```
lbu  $5, 1($3)
sb   $6, 12($3)
```

... will *write* different data to the graphics card (if $3 is an address in video RAM)!

So replacing the three instructions by a single instruction only works if you are working on "normal" RAM.

Comment: Good point about modifying `$4`.  The instruction sequence is pointlessly complex, using a variable shift instead of immediate which could have got the job done without an extra register.  And for some reason uses an arithmetic right shift, even though sign-extension is blown away later.  Perhaps intentional obfuscation?